# What is the point of returning a Multi instead of a Uni with RestEasy?

Tags: quarkus, resteasy, mutiny, quarkus-reactive

I am using RESTEasy Reactive with a MongoDB / Panache and **I am trying to understand what the point of the .stream() methods (when using REST)**.

In several examples ([quarkus docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive), [video](https://youtu.be/-OO2fQZ-Anw?t=2829), [medium article](https://medium.com/geekculture/creating-a-reactive-crud-blog-app-with-mongodb-quarkus-and-panache-54d659cf8dcb), etc.) a Multi is used as a return value for a GET Request. How does this make sense, since the HTTP call is a one-shot call?

- MongoDB (or databases in general, for that matter don't really stream, do they?
- Wouldn't it make more sense to return a Uni< List>> instead of a multi?
- Does it ever make sense to return a Multi via REST?

I tried to delay each item of the Multi stream, but as I expected I only get the response after the 5 seconds are over:

```
@GET
@Path("stream")
public Multi<Integer> streamTest() {
    return Multi.createFrom()
            .items(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            .onItem().call(i -> {
                Duration delay = Duration.ofSeconds(1);
                return Uni.createFrom().nullItem().onItem().delayIt().by(delay);
            });
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I've tested your code with one of the quickstarts](https://github.com/DavideD/quarkus-quickstarts/commit/786f1b698a72dc4f35d2bfa3c1f8d5c26855b3a1) and I think the reason you don't see it as a stream is because of the header and the client you are using to read the response.

It works fine for me when I open it in Firefox, but not when I read it in the terminal with [Httpie](https://httpie.io/).

If you change the code and add an empty `@Produces` annotation on top of it, it should work as expected with all clients because the response header now will be `text/event-stream`:

```
    @GET
    @Path("stream")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS) // or just @Produces
    public Multi<Integer> getStream() {
        return Multi.createFrom()
                .items( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
                .onItem().call( i -> {
                    Duration delay = Duration.ofSeconds( 2 );
                    return Uni.createFrom().nullItem().onItem().delayIt().by( delay );
                } );
    }
```

So, it's really about making sure that the response uses the right  header for your use case.

That said, everything else you say makes sense. At the moment, running a query on the database doesn't return a stream and therefore returning a Multi is usually not helpful. That's why the API in [Panache](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache) and [Hibernate Reactive](https://staging.hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.1/reference/html_single/) for queries return a Uni.

One use case I can think of for Multi is when you have a message driven application. In this case you might want to update a web page or some other component as soon as a message is received on a channel. There is [an example of this in the guide that uses Quarkus and Kafka](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#receiving-messages-from-kafka).

There are also a couple of guides with an [introduction to Mutiny](https://quarkus.io/guides/mutiny-primer#reactive-streams) and how you can use it for [Flow control and backpressure](https://quarkus.io/blog/mutiny-back-pressure/)